# How can I download Play Framework 2.3.3?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

I'm trying out `Play Framework` for the first time, and I used activator to create a Play 2.3.4 project.  When I use the UI and try to inspect requests / actors, I get this message:

```
No requests found. There could be two reasons for this: 
either there haven't been any requests to your 
Play application yet or you're running an unsupported 
Play version (>2.3.3)
```

Since the inspection stuff seems pretty cool, I wanted to see it in action, so I'd like to install 2.3.3.

On the play download page (https://www.playframework.com/download), the links to download the current version (2.3.4) and the previous versions (2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3) all point to the same place (http://downloads.typesafe.com/typesafe-activator/1.2.10/typesafe-activator-1.2.10-minimal.zip).  When I use that activator to create a play project, I get the same 2.3.4 version every time.

How can I set up a 2.3.3 project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change in project/plugins.sbt line:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.3")
```

And then call `reload` or restart activator (sbt)